# Specify bridge from command line

Tags: configuration, bridge

Is there a way to specify a bridge while starting Tor, from command line? I'm working on a script that runs multiple instances of Tor and I find it easier to add the bridge (all the instances are going to use the same bridge) on the command that runs the instance itself, instead of editing the torrc file after.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: If I have a hidden service, do I need bridges for that service ? Or, bridges are just about client side?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the information into some files, say `bridge.1`, `bridge.2` etc. Inside the file are lines with bridges like

```
Bridge 127.0.0.1:4567 0123456789ABCDEF
```

Besides this bridge files you should also have a `torrc` file all other settings. Now you can start the Tor software with a line like

```
tor --defaults-torrc torrc -f bridge.1
```

The first option takes your default `torrc` as argument and is always the same. The second option contains the file with bridge information. You can vary this file depending which bridges you want to use.

Comment: Hm? Yes, you can pass bridges via the commandline, just like any other Tor config option. Just do: /path/to/tor usebridges 1 bridge "127.0.0.1:4567 0123456789ABCDEF". (You'll need to use quotes so the shell doesn't mangle it.)