# TOR Bridge command line

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm trying to start TOR with the command line option tor Bridge obfs4 ip:port Fingerprint but get these errors:

Apr 13 02:03:47.090 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'ip:port'.  Failing.

Apr 13 02:03:47.090 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

Can I not add a bridge through command line? What's wrong?

Comment: You need to substitute an actual IP address for `ip`, a port for `port`, and a fingerprint for `fingerprint`. Do you want to run Tor (on the command line), or the Tor Browser? If you're really just trying to run the Tor Browser, there are steps during the initialisation that will walk you through how to configure bridges.

Comment: Of course I'm using a real ip, port, and fingerprint and not "ip:port fingerprint." I'm using just the command line version.

Comment: Okay - apologies :) Have a look at the following previous answer: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/specify-bridge-from-command-line. You'd need to use the Bridge line in conjunction with a ClientTransportPlugin, as per the obsf4 instructions at https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4. I believe that can just go into the same file as your Bridge settings.